# Craft Commerce: Sell digital products from pool of predefined license keys

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-digitalproducts

We’ve been asked to build a shop to sell e-books. The e-books are published by a third party and we will receive a list of pre-defined license keys (thus stock can run out).

The plugin [Digital Products](https://github.com/craftcms/digital-products) creates license keys by itself. The plugin allows to get the keys instead by a module/plugin.

Has anyone done that? How do you deal with stock (as the plugin Digital Products works without stock, instead endless licenses can be sold).

Do you alternatively see a possibilty to use Commerce without Digital Products and send a key from commerce instead?

Thanks for your thoughts!